# android how to hide the status bar without hiding the title bar

Tags: android, statusbar

In my application i  am working with canvas. I am drawing on canvas. I put canvas color as white. When my app open the canvas is visible along with above status bar.
But i want my canvas should take the full screen. means that Notification status bar should disapear when i run that app bt not the title bar(bcz i m using some custom title bar)
How can i do that?

By using below code i gave custom title,

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);
```

Now i am trying to hide status bar using below code in activity-

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

But it shows force close.
Give me a way how to do that?

Comment: Can you show us the error as well as where you are using the part of code.

Comment: yes,  08-07 11:20:31.831: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(916): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.v3.scribeair.lite/com.v3.scribeair.lite.ScribeAirActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features

Comment: but themes.xml is not there in my app. Where i can find?

Comment: "But i want my canvas should take the full screen" -- this is not possible on Android 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE` after setting `Theme.NoTitleBar`. It's enough to use just this theme. Do not set all these flags in code.

**EDIT**: Seems I misunderstood your question. I read it again carefully and now I see you're asking about Android 2.x and its notification bar. Your `onCreate()` method should look like this:

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.name);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

You mustn't set `Theme.NoTitleBar` or `Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` for this activity. Just use the default `Theme` or don't specify any theme at all.

Comment: will status bar disappear and custom title get visible by doing like this?

Comment: No, it won't. If you mean Android 3.x, then the title bar is optional and the status bar is necessary because it contains such buttons as home and back. Android 3.x doesn't require these buttons to be hardware.

Comment: There is any other way ti fix my problem?

Comment: I'm not sure but I'll answer you if I know the answer.

Comment: Get rid of the custom title and simply put it in your layout above your `Canvas` using a `LinearLayout`. Then, you can hide the title bar and status bar.

Answer (score 3):

It's enough to remove the line

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

But if you want to display  full screen (without action bar) write too

```
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


  setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_eb);
```

Answer (score 1):

Am going to tell you how to tackle the title bar and the system notification panel individually and perfectly.
Use one or both as per Your Need.

1.**Do not apply any theme to the Activity through XML.**

2.Now, go the corr. Java file and add these lines
inside onCreate()..
 **after** super.onCreate()..

Part.a. to remove just Title Bar

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Part.b. to remove the System notification panel

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Do not forget to follow them with the usual

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout_name);
```