# Hide status bar android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How to hide status bar android 4.1.2 ?
i want solution to hide the status bar on version 4.1.2

i want to hide status bar on my application

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);    
layout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

this code not work on version 4.1.2

Comment: what do u mean by status bar..Do u mean title bar

Comment: Have a look on 
[How to hide status bar in Android][1]


and [how to hide the status bar without hiding the title bar][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431365/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-android
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970884/android-how-to-hide-the-status-bar-without-hiding-the-title-bar

Comment: thanks,but are not work on version 4.2

Answer (score 20):

Since Jellybean (4.1) there is a new method that doesn't rely on the WindowManager. Instead use setSystemUiVisibility off of the Window, this gives you more granular control over the system bars than using WindowManager flags. Here is a full example:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) { //ye olde method
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
} else { // Jellybean and up, new hotness
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Hide the status bar.
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    // Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
    // status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if(actionBar != null) {
         actionBar.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: useful and hilarious, +1.
Btw remember to check whether actionBar is null, just in case
if (actionBar != null){ actionBar.hide(); }

Answer (score 12):

Add this to your manifest file under the activity tag in which you want to hide status bar

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

and you are done :)

Comment: i am want to my application only, no for all application

Answer (score 8):

add these lines in oncreate() method

```
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);// hide statusbar of Android
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: call it after setContentView();

Comment: call it before setContentView();

Answer (score 3):

Hope this is what you are looking for.. add this before setcontentview :

```
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work

```
 public static void hideStatusBar(Activity activity) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = activity.getWindow().getAttributes();
    attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    activity.getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
    activity.getWindow().clearFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
  }



public static void showStatusBar(Activity activity) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = activity.getWindow().getAttributes();
    attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    activity.getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
    activity.getWindow().addFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this code in your onCreate method

```
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: He is asking Status/notification bar not the Title bar

Answer (score 0):

write the line in this `onWindowFocusChanged()` method

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
}
```