# Android hide status bar, compatibility

Tags: java, android, statusbar, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have the following code to hide the status bar taken from http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html and [Hide status bar android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904166/hide-status-bar-android)

```
    //hide statut bar
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) { //ye olde method
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    } else { // Jellybean and up, new hotness
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        // Hide the status bar.
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        // Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
        // status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
    }
```

I get an error on `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN`;

it seems that `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` doesn't exist anymore in View.

How to fix it? please thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It exists since API16. You must build your app against API16 (or higher)