# How to hide notification bar during live stream

Tags: android, streaming, android-notification-bar

I have created live streaming app but when I play stream in landscape mode, notification bar keeps appearing so I want to know how to hide notification bar during live stream.

I want to hide when I play stream, I don't want to hide on app main layout.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the question to include the details you mentioned in your comment, which are necessary to identify the specific problem. Please include in your question as much detail as possible and refrain from adding those in comments. You can also delete your latest comment. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So do you want to hide "notification bar" (status bar) in landscape mode only?

Have a look at this link: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904166/hide-status-bar-android) might also help.