# Android how to hide status bar without ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

is it possible to hide status bar:

[image]

And show action bar without it?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970884/android-how-to-hide-the-status-bar-without-hiding-the-title-bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this..

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way .In your manifest `xml`, at application level set this:

```
<activity
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

I hope it will works

Comment: Doesn't this hide the Title Bar as well?